# Yarn global install: "adonis: command not found"

Tags: yarnpkg, adonis.js

Installed Adonis with `yarn` on Ubuntu 18 (running on WSL2 VM):

```
pomatti@NT-03024:~/Projects/myApp$ yarn global add @adonisjs/cli
yarn global v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "@adonisjs/cli@4.0.12" with binaries:
      - adonis
Done in 3.29s.
```

However when I try to run it, the command is not found:

```
pomatti@NT-03024:~/Projects/myApp$ adonis
adonis: command not found
```

What is odd is that my `package.json` commands are working properly and my app is started, but I am not able to call `adonis` directly in the command line (the global installation).

For example, `yarn migration && adonis serve --dev --debug` works.

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "adonis serve",
    "migration": "adonis migration:run",
    "start": "yarn migration && yarn serve",
    "dev": "yarn migration && adonis serve --dev --debug",
    "lint": "yarn eslint"
  },
```

Comment: If you install with npm it's working? `> npm i -g @adonisjs/cli`

Comment: @CrBast yes, it did work. can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to install with NPM. Command:

```sh
> npm i -g @adonisjs/cli
```

[Official documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/installation#_installing_adonisjs)

Answer (score 0):

For CLI tools installed with `yarn global` to work, you need to have the global yarn `bin` directory in your `PATH`. By default the yarn bin dir should be `~/.yarn/bin`. To double check if that's right on your system and the adonis executable exists (assuming you've already run `yarn global add @adonisjs/cli`):

```
ls ~/.yarn/bin/adonis
```

(Mine is there).

To add that to my `PATH`:

```
cat > ~/.bashrc.d/yarn <<EOF
PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:\$PATH"
EOF
chmod +x ~/.bashrc.d/yarn
. ~/.bashrc.d/yarn
```

Then double check `PATH`: `echo $PATH`. Here's mine (after the above - your may not have all of these paths, but so long as it has `/home/user/.yarn/bin` - where `user` is your username):

```
/home/user/.yarn/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/lib/git-core:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```